# import libraries into python scrapy shell.

Tags: python, namespaces, scrapy

I launch the shell by :

```
scrapy shell 'some_url'
```

I want to use numpy in the shell:

```
import numpy
a = numpy.random.random(2)
a = array([ 0.64836678,  0.72713776])
```

These all worked fine. The problem comes when I try use numpy in a function definition:

```
In [23]: def foo(n): return numpy.random.random(n) 
In [24]: foo(2) 
In [24]: foo(2)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-3ab2f4e33a15> in <module>()
----> 1 foo(2)

<ipython-input-23-8383e2a3c452> in foo(n)
----> 1 def foo(n) : return numpy.random.random(n)

NameError: global name 'numpy' is not defined
```

My current solution is:

```
def foo(n) :import numpy ; return numpy.random.random(n)
```

Can someone help explain this problem and propose more elegant solution?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `numpy.random.random(n)` Python looks for `numpy` name in local variables, then if it was not found, it looks for it in global variables.

It's clear that if you haven't imported numpy there is no such name:

```
NameError: global name 'numpy' is not defined
```

If you do

```
def foo(n) :import numpy ; return numpy.random.random(n)
```

you import `numpy` module and keep a reference to it in the local (inside function `foo`) variable `numpy`. So your call `numpy.random.random(n)` works fine.

If you import `numpy` into global namespace, it will also work:

```
import numpy
def foo(n):
    return numpy.random.random(n)
```

Ensure that you you did `import numpy`, because everything works fine here:

```
In [1]: import numpy

In [2]: numpy.random.random(2)
Out[2]: array([ 0.05183811,  0.18187864])

In [3]: def foo(n): return numpy.random.random(n)

In [4]: foo(2)
Out[4]: array([ 0.19754933,  0.88955471])
```

Comment: hello, warwaruk, please re-read my question. I problem is: your solution doesn't work in scrapy shell. Thanks

Comment: @johnniac, everything works fine here -- see my update

Comment: I tried, same error. My problem is not about ipython, it's about scrapy shell. thanks ,

Comment: Yes, that was `scrapy shell`

Comment: hmmm, interesting, guess i will re-intall the packages. Thanks